# override templates in django-allauth

Tags: django, templates, overriding, django-allauth

I have read all the possible solutions I can find on StackOverflow and been through the allauth documents. Still not able to point to my local (*in my Django project*) templates instead of the allauth ones (i.e. login, signup, etc.)

**1. Moved my applications before the allauth ones in settings.py INSTALLED_APPS, so that it looks like this:**

```
'users', #my custom user model app
'date_track.apps.DateTrackConfig', # main app

'django.contrib.sites',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
```

]

**2. Modified my project structure and moved allauth templates (login, signup, etc.) to this location.**

- The structure now looks like this:

my_project/templates/allauth/
inside this dir I have the 3 allauth dirs:
1. account
2. openid
3.socialaccount

And inside these dirs I have all the allauth templates,
plus, base.html

**3. I have modified my TEMPLATES Setting in settings.py to look like this:**

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 
'templates', 'allauth','accounts', 'socialaccount')],
```

Yet, whenever I access the link off my home page (which inherits from my project's base.html), it heads right over to the templates in:
site-packages/allauth/templates/account directory.

base.html has the links to the templates as follows:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   <li class="nav-item">
     <p><h6>You are Logged in as <I>{{user.username}}</I></h6></p>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'account_email' 
     %}">Email</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">Sign 
     out</a>
  </li>
{% else %}
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Sign in</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link " href="{% url 'account_signup' %}" 
    tabindex="-1">Sign up</a>
 </li>
{% endif %}
```

I must be doing something silly, but I can't seem to find it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use https://github.com/danihodovic/django-allauth-ui

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have your template directory structure match this:

```
# correct
templates\account
templates\openid
templates\socialaccount
```

It looks like you have one to many directories:

```
# incorrect
templates\allauth\account
templates\alluth\openid
templates\alluth\socialaccount
```

Link to the allauth source[1] for reference

[1] https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/templates

Comment: This only works in the project folder, right? Not in application folders. Is there a way to get this working using an app folder instead of the main project folder?